# UITableView Segue

Tags: tableview, segue

Im trying to make a small project. Could someone help me understand why the segue does not work?

```
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"

@interface CarTableViewController ()




@end

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc]
                     initWithObjects:@"Chevy",
                     @"BMW",
                     @"Toyota",
                     @"Volvo",
                     @"Smart", nil];

    self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Volt",
                      @"Mini",
                      @"Venza",
                      @"S60",
                      @"Fortwo", nil];

    self.carImages = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"chevy_volt.jpg",
                      @"mini_clubman.jpg",
                      @"toyota_venza.jpg",
                      @"volvo_s60.jpg",
                      @"smart_fortwo.jpg", nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _carModels.count;
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [self.carMakes
                           objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [self.carModels
                            objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:
                         [self.carImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];

    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}
```

The code work´s fine, and loads a tableView, but I need to go to CarDetailViewControler and I´m using the following code, but it does not work.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                    indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects: [self.carMakes
                                                                 objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carImages objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: See these [Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22761617/3681880) or [Swift answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31936367/3681880)

Answer (score 4):

In the storyboard did you use a cell prototype? If so, did you control-drag from the prototype to the destination viewcontroller and create the named segue?

The method you are using requires the segue to be defined completely in the storyboard, meaning the trigger for the segue is tied to the cell prototype.

You can manually trigger a segue using:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCarDetails" sender:self];
```

in your:

`tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as an alternative.