# Unable to Navigate From UIViewController to UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am working with `UICollectionViewController`. When I navigate from a `UIViewController` to a `UICollectionViewController` by using `UINavigationController` an exception occurred with message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter.
```

I don't know why this happened.

I am using a simple `UICollectionViewController` without any coding (i.e. by default created file). Its file name is 'NewCollectionViewController.m' & 'NewCollectionViewController.h'.

My Xcode version is 6.1.1.

My navigation code is:

```
NewCollectionViewController *CVController = [[NewCollectionViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CVController animated:YES];
```

I just want to navigate from `UIViewController` to `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the first time you play with `UICollectionViewController`.

Just as the exception reason said `UICollectionView` must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter. The proper init method of `UICollectionViewController` is

```
 - (instancetype)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Check The root View having `NavigationController` and make sure `storyBoard` `Identifier` set.

```
NewCollectionViewController *CVController = (NewCollectionViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBordIdentifier"]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CVController animated:YES];
```

[Push to new ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected/22759350#22759350)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 
`[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionView class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];`

in NewCollectionViewController class

Answer (score 0):

Create `UICollectionViewCell` class and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class and add them to your `UICollectionViewController` class.