# objective c - click table row and go to another page

Tags: ios, objective-c, tablerow

I want to user click **table row** then after it user will go to other page. The page has Storyboard ID "Other View" and Restoration ID "Other View". 
But I can't go to purposed view

This is my code :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tabel cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indeksBaris
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TampilanCell";
    TabelBeritaCell *cell = (TabelBeritaCell *)[tabel dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"nilai : %d", indeksBaris.row );
    //detecting NIB of table view
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    //Go To View Controller which have identifier "Other View"
    UIViewController *otherViewCon;
    otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];

    cell.judulBerita.text =  [listBerita objectAtIndex:indeksBaris.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This code doesn't work :

```
UIViewController *otherViewCon;
otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
```

**UPDATED**
I have insert new code. I **use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method** but it doesn't work :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIViewController *otherViewCon;
        otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: show the code of didSelectRowAtInedxPath method

Comment: No, I haven't used that method. I will try first...

Comment: Why don't you try what I wrote in my answer: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:tableView];` You don't need to create a new UIViewController

Comment: please read tableview delegate methods so you will understand for what which method is useful.

Comment: @andika_kurniawan, have you checked that, your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath ` is called or not ?

Comment: TableView delegate set?

Comment: I have set the delegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:tableView];
}
```

If you want to pass a variable or perform an action before it segues, do the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        //Do something
        Detail *detailController = (Detail*)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

If you want to know how to name a segue, here is a great tutorial from apple docs: [Naming Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html)

Comment: This code works. But I have error "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ViewController: 0x79442370>) has no segue with identifier 'Other View'"

Actually, I have create Storyboard ID and Restoration ID in the view named with 'Other View'

Comment: Select the segue in the storyboard, then at the upper right hand side button and name the segue there. Here is a good tutorial on naming segues: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: Don't be sorry!! We've all been there!! Just let me know if this gives the right answer

Comment: I think the down voter on this post is just jealous that you are a woman and you can code :) Anyway, I think this post is good so I will upvote.

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciative it!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct. just i feel problem in finding `UIStoryboard` object .replace following things may this work fine.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIViewController *otherViewCon;
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your_storyboard_name" bundle:nil];// like Main.storyboard for used "Main"
        otherViewCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't think @andika_kurniawan want to create a new viewController prgrammatically. I think the problem is just segueing.

Comment: @Jessica, i am not creating new viewController. i am just getting reference of viewController programmatically that already exists.

Comment: Oops. ur right!! But why are you creating a new storyboard?

Comment: Once again i am taking reference of UIStoryboard that already exists.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write navigation code in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method.

Or you can directly go to another view controller by drawing push segue in storyboard.No need to write code.

[How to make a push segue when a UITableViewCell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected)

Comment: Drawing push segue from table view? I can't do it! I can only draw if the element is button.

Comment: If your going to same page after selecting any row then you can draw push segue from your table.

Comment: check answer click on link hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
      NSString * storyboardIdentifier = @"storyboardName";// for example "Main.storyboard" then you have to take only "Main"
      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardIdentifier bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
      UIViewController * UIVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVCStoryboardID"];
     [self presentViewController:UIVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its help you. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
  if(indexpath.row==0)//means you click row 0 
   {
     UIViewController *otherView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"otherview"];
        [self presentViewController:otherView animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
  else
   {
     UIViewController *detailView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];
        [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in here showDataVC is a my new file name for second ViewController.
in a first created a object of new file and initialize.
and initialize showDataVC with object to use object in pushviewcontroller.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    showDataVc *objshowDataVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showDataVc"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objshowDataVc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement your code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. And please read the documentations before writing code n research before you put questions here.