# Uitableview cell transition

Tags: ios

My tableViewcell is in array and i want to select diary cell from which i need to navigate to next screen.i dont know what to implement in did select row method.please help me out

```
table=[[UITableView alloc]init];
    table.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame));
    table.delegate=self;
    table.dataSource=self;
    table.backgroundColor=RGBCOLOR(255,255,255);
    tabledata=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Me and My stuff",@"Upgrade Membership",@"Diary",@"Progress",@"Friends",@"My awards and points",@"Messages",@"Blogs",@"Fun stuff",@"Remainders",@"Settings",@"Signout",nil];
    table.backgroundColor=RGBCOLOR(255,239,213);
    table.sectionFooterHeight=44;
    table.sectionHeaderHeight=44;
    table.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    self.view.backgroundColor=RGBCOLOR(255,239,213);

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellidentifier =@"table";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        cell.opaque=NO;
        cell.backgroundColor=RGBCOLOR(255,239,213);
        cell.textLabel.textColor=RGBCOLOR(32,178,170);
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;


}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



}
```

Comment: r u using storyboard if yes , show your cell for rowatindex method

Comment: No i am not using storyboard...everything done programatically

Comment: ok show your didfinishlaunch option and cellfor rowatindexpath

Comment: Previously answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that the tableview contains in  our first view controller

**1. SecondViewController.h**

```
 @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullName;
```

**2. SecondViewController.m**

```
@synthisize fullName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 NSLog(@"name ==%@",fullName);


[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

**3. FirstViewController.m**

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (indexPath.row==2) // this is diary cell
{
SecondViewController *temp = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

 temp.fullName=[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];

}
else
{
 // do nothing 
}
}
```

Comment: @Arun - how do I know in which your object contains diary , this is the normal way for push the data using progmatically

Comment: @Arun - check the updated answer, I modified answer in **didSelectRow** method

Comment: @Arun -- anything else do u need