# IOS: Navigate through tableView and show table view data on next view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

in my project i am using a custom `UITableView` in which i passes 2 array (image and name) arrays are showing on `UITableView`. Now i want to when i click on any cell of table view the credentials of `UITableViewCell` to be display on next View in which i take an `UIImageView` (for image) and UILabel (for name display). i also import the VC on which i have to display image and name.
please suggest me code to display name and image on another view

i am using the following codes

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FriendsViewController : UIViewController<UISearchDisplayDelegate , UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

    {
        UITableView *friendslisttable;
        NSMutableArray *friendslist;
        NSMutableArray *friendsnamearray;
        NSMutableArray *profilepicarray;
        UIImageView * frndprofpic;
        UILabel *friendnamelabel;

        NSArray *searchResults;
    }
    @end
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Friends";

    friendslisttable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,110 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] ;
    friendslisttable.delegate = self;
    friendslisttable. dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:friendslisttable];

    friendsnamearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"friend1",@"friend12",@"friend13",@"friend14",@"friend15",@"friend16",@"friend17",@"friend18",@"friend19",@"friend20",@"friend21 ",@"friend22",@"", nil];

    profilepicarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"download3.jpeg", @"12045540_717548405011935_7183980263974928829_o.jpg" , @"download4.jpeg", @"download5.jpeg", @"download6.jpg", @"download12.jpeg", @"download13.jpeg", @"download16.jpeg",@"download3.jpeg", @"download6.jpg", @"download12.jpeg", @"download16.jpeg", @"  ",  nil];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Method -------------------->>>>

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}    

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return searchResults.count;
    }
    else {
        return friendsnamearray.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellidentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier ];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    friendslisttable  = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        friendslisttable = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else
    {
        friendslisttable = [friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    frndprofpic = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];

    frndprofpic.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[profilepicarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:frndprofpic];

    friendnamelabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 250, 50)];
    friendnamelabel.text = [friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    friendnamelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Regular" size:20];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:friendnamelabel];

    return  cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!indexPath.row) {
        ProfileViewController *u = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected

Comment: i am using a custom tableview please tell me what changes i have to made in didSelectRow method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the cases such as yours I suggest you to subclass the table view cell. Create 2 properties in your case for the profile image and for the name. Override setters of these properties and set the view components as needed.

On the event of did select row you may now use the same properties of the custom cell which can be set as properties to your target controller before pushing it.

But if you want to do it proper you should always use a model class (MyUserClass) which can then be inserted into the custom cell and the view controller. This way you keep only one property for both the input and output. Also if your model class changes or if you need to display more data not much of the code will change. For instance imagine your cell stays the same but on the view controller you wish to also add the user location: All you need to do is add the location property to the model class and then use it only in the view controller. (if you did it with multiple properties the cell would need that property to be collected even though it does not display it).

**Let me give you a nice example on some uses of communications with the table view, table view cell and the owner (usually the view controller).**

This is a display of how to get the data from cell nicely as well as hooking a custom control (the button) to the cell and notify the owner of the event with the appropriate data.

Note this is all done programmatically so you can see all the code done. This may all be done with storyboards though.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyModel;
@class MyTableViewCell;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

- (void)specialCellButtonPressed:(MyTableViewCell *)sender selectedModel:(MyModel *)model;

@end
```

Source:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"


#pragma mark - My model
/*
 MyModel:
 Model that we will use to hold the data
*/
@interface MyModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *descriptionText;

@end

#pragma mark - My model
/*
 MyTableViewCell:
 Custom table view cell to show the MyModel data
 */
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyModel *model;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *specialButton; // have the secondary action
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyViewController *owner; // note this may also be solved with a custom delegate but we want to bind this one to a concrete class that has type of MyViewController. Be careful to set this property to "weak"

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)setModel:(MyModel *)model
{
    _model = model; // standard asignment

    // set some views to show the actual data
    self.textLabel.text = model.title;
    self.detailTextLabel.text = model.descriptionText;
}

#pragma mark - custom button on the cell

// lazy load for the button
- (UIButton *)specialButton
{
    if(_specialButton == nil)
    {
        // put the button on the right side of the frame
        _specialButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, self.contentView.frame.size.width*.5f, self.contentView.frame.size.width*.5f)];
        [_specialButton addTarget:self action:@selector(spectialButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_specialButton];
    }
    return _specialButton;
}

#pragma mark - layout

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // reposition the custom view if needed
    self.specialButton.frame = CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, self.contentView.frame.size.width*.5f, self.contentView.frame.size.width*.5f);
}

#pragma mark - actions

- (void)spectialButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // just report this to the delegate or rather the owner in this case
    [self.owner specialCellButtonPressed:self selectedModel:self.model];
}

@end


#pragma mark - My model
/*
 MyViewController:
 A view controller showing the table view
 */
@interface MyViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *models;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

#pragma mark - lifetime

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // fill some data for our table view
    NSMutableArray *models = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSInteger i=0; i<24; i++)
    {
        MyModel *model = [[MyModel alloc] init];
        model.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", (int)(i+1)];
        model.descriptionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a cell with index: %d", (int)(i)];
        [models addObject:model];
    }
    self.models = models;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

// lazy load from table view
- (UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(_tableView == nil)
    {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    }
    return _tableView;
}

#pragma mark - layout

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // reposition the table view if needed
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(.0f, .0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

#pragma mark - table view

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.models.count;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.model = self.models[indexPath.row]; // assign the model from our list
    cell.owner = self;
    return cell;
}

// standard cell selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyModel *model = cell.model;
    /*
     Alternative if we have the data array (as we do in this case):

     MyModel *model = self.models[indexPath.row];

     */

    NSLog(@"Selected model: %@", model);
    // do whatever with the model
}

#pragma mark - special

- (void)specialCellButtonPressed:(MyTableViewCell *)sender selectedModel:(MyModel *)model
{
    NSLog(@"Special button for model pressed: %@", model);
}

@end




@implementation MyModel

// override description to get some usefull data
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%p> %@ (%@)", self, self.title, self.descriptionText];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Create properties in ProfileViewController:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic)UIImage *profilePicture;   
 @property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *name;
```

Modify your didSelectMethod as below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (!indexPath.row) {
    ProfileViewController *u = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
    UIImage *profileImage = [profilepicarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *name = [friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    u.profilePicture = profileImage;
    u.name = name;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Picture not showing or both picture and name? check if profilepicarry contains UIImage objects. In viewdidLoad() of profileviewcontroller add breakpoint and check if self.profileImage and self.name contains value that we pass from tableviewcell. Let me know if it worked or not. Thanks

Comment: This means that problem is when you fill UIImageView and UILabel. Add break points on those areas. check if result is same. And then make sure you fill uiimageview and uilabel correctly.

Comment: and also click is only working on the first row i want it work on all the cells

Comment: check if didselect called when you select on different cell. also check that profilepicarray and friendsnamearray contains value at indexPath.row

Answer (score 1):

You need add two property on `ProfileViewController.h`.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSStirng* str;

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIImage* img;
```

in `ProfileViewController.m`

```
@synthesize str;
@synthesize img;
```

In your

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (!indexPath.row) {
    ProfileViewController *u = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];

    u.str = [friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    u.img = [UIImage imageNamed:[profilepicarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
}
}
```

And your in `ProfileViewController` use as

```
self.img
self.str
```

hope it helps you .

Answer (score 1):

Use your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to pass the value.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (!indexPath.row) 
         {
            //get selected image and label text  here.
           NSString *lbltxt=[friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           UIImage *img=[friendsnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           //pass this two value into `NSUserDefaults` and get from  the `NSUserDefaults` to another viewcontroller

           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) forKey:key];
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lbltxt forKey:@"preferenceName"];
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            ProfileViewController *u = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You havent passed data which is to be displayed in "ProfileViewController" , so how would VC would know what to show.

You need to pass data which is to be displayed on next VC before navigating to "ProfileViewController"
You can pass data by creating an object of "ProfileViewController" and thereby accessing its members through the object itself.
You can access and modify the members of the ProfileViewController class and use them to display data in this class.