# UITableView example for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've been working with Swift and iOS for a number of months now. I am familiar with many of the ways things are done but I'm not good enough that I can just write things up without looking. I've appreciated Stack Overflow in the past for providing quick answers to get me back on track with topics I've gotten rusty on (for example, [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)).

iOS's `UITableView` is in this category for me. I've done them a few times, but I forget what the details are. I couldn't find another question on StackOverflow that just asks for a basic example and I'm looking for something shorter than many of the tutorials that are online (although [this one](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) is very good).

I am providing an answer below for my future reference and yours.

Comment: here is a tutorial with explanations. less than 10 mins and step by step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExZRzXhJitc

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The example below is an adaptation and simplification of [a longer post](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) from We ❤ Swift. This is what it will look like:

[image]

## Create a New Project

It can be just the usual Single View Application.

## Add the Code

Replace the *ViewController.swift* code with the following:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    // Data model: These strings will be the data for the table view cells
    let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
    
    // cell reuse id (cells that scroll out of view can be reused)
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    
    // don't forget to hook this up from the storyboard
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Register the table view cell class and its reuse id
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        
        // (optional) include this line if you want to remove the extra empty cell divider lines
        // self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        // This view controller itself will provide the delegate methods and row data for the table view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.animals.count
    }
    
    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
        
        // set the text from the data model
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }
}
```

Read the in-code comments to see what is happening. The highlights are

- The view controller adopts the `UITableViewDelegate` and  `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.
- The `numberOfRowsInSection` method determines how many rows there will be in the table view.
- The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method sets up each row.
- The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called every time a row is tapped.

## Add a Table View to the Storyboard

Drag a `UITableView` onto your View Controller. Use auto layout to pin the four sides.

[image]

## Hook up the Outlets

<kbd>Control</kbd> drag from the Table View in IB to the `tableView` outlet in the code.

## Finished

That's all. You should be able run your app now.

*This answer was tested with Xcode 9 and Swift 4*

---

## Variations

**Row Deletion**

You only have to add a single method to the basic project above if you want to enable users to delete rows. See [this basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719543/3681880) to learn how.

[image]

**Row Spacing**

If you would like to have spacing between your rows, see [this supplemental example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33931591/3681880).

[image]

**Custom cells**

The default layout for the table view cells may not be what you need. [Check out this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36426858/3681880) to help get you started making your own custom cells.

[image]

**Dynamic Cell Height**

Sometimes you don't want every cell to be the same height. Starting with iOS 8 it is easy to automatically set the height depending on the cell content. [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36422189/3681880) for everything you need to get you started.

[image]

## Further Reading

- [iOS & Swift Tutorial: UITableViewController](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/)
- [iOS Table View Tutorial Using Swift](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-table-view-tutorial-using-swift)

Comment: TODO: add/link to a static table view example

Comment: wonderful answer! I would also add some other common functionality such as eliminating empty tableview rows by adding footer `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()` in viewDidLoad(), adding `cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "image")` for row icon image, and `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor` for cell background

Answer (score 30):

For completeness sake, and for those that do not wish to use the Interface Builder, here's a way of creating the same table as in [Suragch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33234181/810167) entirely programatically - albeit with a different size and position.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
    let animals = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }

}
```

Make sure you have remembered to `import UIKit`.

Comment: It would be great if you could add the code needed to have the table view fill the screen. Currently it just occupies the rectangle you hardcoded.

Comment: @ChrisGillum, [here is how your would add the constraints programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36263784/3681880).

Comment: tableView.registerClass has been changed to tableView.register for those who are wondering.

Answer (score 12):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

1. Add UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate delegated to your class.
2. Create table view variable and array.
3. In viewDidLoad create table view.
4. Call table view delegates
5. Call table view delegate functions based on your requirement.

```
import UIKit
// 1
class yourViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

// 2
var yourTableView:UITableView = UITableView()
let myArray = ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 3
    yourTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: view.frame.width-20, height: view.frame.height-200)
    self.view.addSubview(yourTableView)

    // 4
    yourTableView.dataSource = self
    yourTableView.delegate = self

}

// 5
// MARK - UITableView Delegates
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    if self. myArray.count > 0 {
        cell?.textLabel!.text = self. myArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50.0
}
```

If you are using storyboard, no need for Step 3.

But you need to create IBOutlet for your table view before Step 4.

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5**

If you only want a tableView on your screen then you can implement `UITableViewController` to your `ViewController` and do like this to show a simple `tableViewController` with a label in it.

Swift file

```
class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {
    let array = ["GAFDGSG","VSBFFSB","BFBFB"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        array.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

And in storyboard create a UITableViewController with mentioning the identifier like this

MainStoryboard

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//    UITableViewCell set Identify "Cell"
//    UITableView Name is  tableReport

UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableReport: UITableView!  

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5;
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableReport.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Report Name"
            return cell;
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation about how this is different than the other answers?

Comment: For future reference: This is a simplified version - it contains the bare minimum for a tableview. That's the difference.m

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 4 version.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{ 
    var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
    let animals = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return animals.count
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }

}
```