# Avoid adding subview on cellforrowatindexpath

Tags: ios, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 100)
var retCell = UITableViewCell(frame: cellFrame)
 var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(8,30,tableView.frame.width-8-8,65))
            textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                                retCell.addSubview(textView)
                                if(reqGrpIndex == 0){
                reqGrpIndex = reqGrpIndex + 1
            }
}
```

Why shouldn't we add subview on this function?? How can change the code to be a good practice for doing same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You are using this function in a wrong way.This function is used to initiate tableView cell and load data to that initiated table view cell.And also it's a good practice to reusable cells and load related information to that cell. By the way this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift) has really good accepted answer and this answer will help you to understand tableView concept well.And also there is nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-table-view-basics--cms-25160) which explain about tableView

Comment: So i should use a custom cell? the views for each cell are different in my app.

Comment: You should provide information in order to help your question.  :)

Comment: for example, i have two cases for the cell, case A: Display button. Case B: Display textview.

Comment: I've added to links in my answer. Have a look :) You should learn about tableView Basic things first