# how to display details of one person at a time in tableview using swift?

Tags: swift

A view controller holds an array of Student objects . At once it displays one of the  student’s details on the view including its name, email, phone etc .how to display details in tableview using swift?

Comment: You should show person name and few details in tableview. You should show entire person details in another view controller. You should pass the person object on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You want to know how to render this data in a tableView?

Comment: This is exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33234181/6414904