# error : type "UserAccView" does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, function, swift3, tableview

So I am trying to add some data returned from a function and I can only access that data from inside that function so I ended up putting the table inside the function but after I did so I received the error above.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class UserAccView: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource {



@IBAction func GetUserInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {



    guard let url = URL(string: "https://goollyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/v0.1/Goolly/User/218910182109") else{return}
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
            print (response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                guard let data_array = json as? NSArray else
                {
                    return
                }
                for i in 0 ..< data_array.count
                {
                    if let data_object = data_array[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                        if  let Body        = data_object["id"] as? String,
                            let InfoId = data_object["TransDate"] as? String,
                            let Title      = data_object["Debt"] as? String,
                            let UserId     = data_object["Crdit"] as? String,
                            let InfoType     = data_object["Desc"] as? String

                        {}
                    }
    }
    }
            func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return (data?.count)!
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                var cell = UITableViewCell()
                cell.textLabel?.text = "cells"
                return cell
            }

    }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make a lot of changes. You need to bring out all TableView methods outside of your `GetUserInfo ` method. then make the data accessible to ViewController and populate the table view

Comment: Please format your code properly, since it's barely readable this way. However, it even seems you have function definitions inside functions... Also don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift, use their native counterparts, Array and Dictionary. And most importantly read the Swift book. You are clearly missing a lot of key concepts that are needed to understand Swift itself and iOS development as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have added the dataSource methods inside your Api Call ? Write those methods outside of your `GetUserInfo IBAction`.

Secondly, now you want to reload the tableview. For that create `IBOutlet for tableview` first and when response comes from the api you can reload the tableview after filling the response in your `data` array.

Lastly don't use `var cell = UITableViewCell()` like this in `cellForRowAt`. It will freeze your tableview . Use it like this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell.
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @IBAction func GetUserInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 2 }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "cells"
            return cell
        }

Comment: david pasztor am totally new to swift sooo thats why am so shit at it lol am also new to this site so am having trouble typing in code blocks lmao

Comment: Here also you have added dataSource methods inside `GetUserInfo`.

Comment: oh sorry i thought u said inside not outside my bad

Comment: Yaah correct it. You can read some tutorials on tableviews first. It's easy once you will surely get it

Comment: now that i got the table out i cant add "data" to it by data i mean this :session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
            print (response)
            }}..........not the whole thing just the received data

Comment: thanks for ur help but since the data isnt in yet i cant mark this as an answer lol

Comment: You can upvote it :) You can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift. It will help you about tableviews basics

Comment: i did but it says my reputation is low

Comment: Not a problem Duck.P