# UITableView heightForRowAt always crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on the UI to make it same as design, I used `heightForRowAt` to make first section's cell's height to 96px, and I tried:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return 96.0
        default:
            return 56.0
        }
}
```

but it crashed and I searched everywhere but the problem was never solved

so I tried for testing:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56.0
}
```

but It also crashed.

Xcode just gives me `Thread 1:signal SIGABRT` Error, and I couldn't find a solution. Why this happening to me?

+++ Console Message When Error Happens

[image: screenshot of console message]

Comment: did you try to go step by step and see when it crashes?

Comment: yes I checked all of functions and It crashed only with it

Comment: Are you sure your datasource array is has right mapping?

Comment: check this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift

Comment: Could you share the entire error?

Comment: I used two sections and I 100% sure my datasource array has no problem. It perfectly works when I erase `heightForRowAt`.

Comment: put a screenshot of the error please

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: Share full code of your tableview data source and delegate along with array

Comment: What is full error message?

Comment: Your datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is crash function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error of thre crash has nothing to do with custom heights that you mentioned. In your method to get the cell for row at index path you are trying to dequeue two cells for same index path...

You must have something like this in your code...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
}
```

And iOS is crashing to let you know that you can only dequeue one cell per index path...

Comment: Thanks! finally I got it

Comment: well, he got it :')