# How to set padding/margin and corner radius to TableViewCell of TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've UITableView and I wants set corner radius and a margin/padding to Top/Right/Left/Bottom. But, if I try set this, my layout is messing. And, when I try: `cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0` fires nil pointer exception.

My layout is like this:

[image]

A example of I like that my layout be:

[image]

I wants that my cells stay "floating" with corner radius and margins, without mess my layout builded.

Also about UITableView, how I remove the unused cells? I have only 3 cells, but TableView shows all cell possibles, leaving others cell not useds.

[image]

Also (4): Why my cells appears united? This not appears "floating"

[image]

Comment: This answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33234181/7698092] will also be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your require layout do below steps.

1. Add `UIView` in you `cell` `contentView` with **Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom Constraint. Like (15, 10, 15, 10)**
2. Select that `UIView` and check `Clip to Bounds` checkmark.
3. Add your required UI inside that `UIView`.
4. Set `UIView` `cornerRadius` inside `layoutSubviews()` inside your `cell` file

And to remove UnUsed `cell` write this line your `viewDidLoad` -> `self.tblVW.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: .zero)`

**Here is demo Link:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/815loyp20r0oetf/Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: Yes, this apparently works, but look my edition, the cells appears a one background white, not stay floating.

Comment: @Augusto, iam not getting your point? upload image that type of output you want.

Comment: @Augusto this link contains the same `layout` like 2nd image, only labels are different.

Comment: @Augusto, did you see this demo?

Comment: Oh yes, this Demo is perfectly what I need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169907/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-augusto).

Comment: I try follows your demo, but I can't obtain the same result. Please you can help me?

Comment: @Augusto, hi what's the problem?

Comment: I did solved, but only works when I create the .xib file checking the box on creating a new cocoatouch class file. If, I create separate, not works.

Comment: @Augusto, ca you give me link of your demo project so I can see it and let you know whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are taking a view inside table view cell on which your all content is present. that is why your using **cell.cellView**

what you need here is that just add this line too if in case you are missing.

```
cell.cellView.clipToBounds = true
```

This should work.

In case you are not taking an **UIView** inside cell content view then follow this steps.

- Take a UIView from object library.
- give it required margins inside cell content view.
- add all your required UI components in this view.
- set **clipToBounds** to true along with **cornerRadius**

Comment: better contextualize your solution, please. I don't know where I set margin to make more easy I design my UI inside margin limits on UIView

Comment: I do other question in my question, if you can reply please do this.