# How to recreate native iOS UI label with border in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a challenge replicating basic UI elements in Xcode.

I am not aware how to replicate elements from this picture:

[image: this picture].

The action that needs to happen is when clicking on "On site", a new view controller is opened.

I have assumed that "On Site" is a `UIButton` sitting on `UIView` white rectangle with grey border on top and bottom.

Is there a different/better way of doing this?

Comment: Create static cell on tableview and implement!

Comment: here is the solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift

Comment: use tableview or [settings bundle](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/adding-settings-to-your-ios-app-cecef8c5497)

Comment: You can use tableview & on selection you can redirect to new view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your UI either using `UITableView` or `UIStackView` embedded in `UIScrollView` (if you have more content on your screen).

If you are going to use UITableView you need to implement custom `UITableViewCell`.
It should contains a `UILabel` for text an `UIImageView` for checkbox. Since iOS doesn't have checkbox control on default. If user taps cell you can detect tap using `UITableViewDelegate` method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

If you are going to use `UIStackView` you can use vertical stack view for two elements.
And for each element you also need horizontal stackView with buttons and imageView for checkbox. By tapping buttons you can open required screen.