# How to pass data from array to multiple label for Quiz app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I should create Quiz app, I just created template and MVC, but cannot understand how to pass data from array with question and answers to label on screen ?
I have 3 screen
1.Screen with "start" button
2.Main screen where I should pass data from array
3.Screen - result

I attached template screen
 [image]

```
struct Question {
    var text: String
    var answers: [Answer]
}

extension Question {
     static func loadData() -> [Question] {
        return [
            Question(
                text:some text",
                answers: [
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Sloupok),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Pikachy),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Lucario),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Slugma),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Vaperon)
                ]
            ),
            Question(
                text:"some text",
                answers: [
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Sloupok),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Pikachy),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Lucario),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Slugma),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Vaperon)
                ]
            ),
            Question(
                text:"some text ?",
                answers: [
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Sloupok),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Pikachy),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Lucario),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Slugma),
                    Answer(text: "", type: .Vaperon)
                ]
            ),
            Question(
                text:"some text?",
                answers: [
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Sloupok),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Pikachy),
                    Answer(text: "Сsome text", type: .Lucario),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Slugma),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Vaperon)
                ]
            ),
            Question(
                text:"some text?",
                answers: [
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Sloupok),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Pikachy),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Lucario),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Slugma),
                    Answer(text: "some text", type: .Vaperon)
                ]
            )
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Collection View for showing question and answers

Comment: But I have stackView  label with switch! I will have five questions and answer options, where I have to choose the appropriate one, move the switch to position “on”and press the “reply” button, to go to the next question

Comment: Create a var currenetQuestion = 0 and update questoin, answers from the array. Once reply button is pressed increment currentQuestion and update question and answers

Answer (score 0):

You can set data to labels one by one, but it is not good solution. If you need dynamic number of answers, it becomes complex to pass data.

I suggest to use TableView. You can create custom cell for displaying answer and use it in your tableview.
Here is good example of using TableView: [UITableView example for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift)

Comment: You need to have references of all labels in your ViewController and set text one by one, something like that:
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

self.lblTitle.text = "blahblah"