# How to change UITableViewCell width?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want my custom cell to occupy not the entire width of the screen, but only part of it and to be in the center of its row.
For example:

[image: example]

You can see little spaces on the left and right sides of each cell.
I was able to achieve this by creating a UIView hierarchy, but then another problem arises for me. So I decided to find out if it is possible to do this without adding additional views?

Comment: If you can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33234181/6183374 maybe you will get a sense how to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

A good approach is using `Auto Layout`. I would recommend using a custom xib that subclasses `UITableViewCell`. Once created, try implementing these constraints in the xib file:

- Leading Space to Container = Margin
- Trailing Space to Container = Margin
- Top Space to Container = 20
- Bottom Space to Container = 20

Hope this helps.