# How to update cell in a tableView from array by using button in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, tableview

So, I was trying to make Birthday App which notes name and birthday of the written textField values. When i press button, those values are saved in two separated Arrays. Those names will be seen on the tableView. I can't see nameArray values on cells but the program builds successfully.

**My question is how can update tableView cell names with the values of my nameArray?**

Thanks in advance

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var birthdayTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTV: UITableView!
    
    var nameArray = [String]()
    var birthdayArray = [String]()
    
    let rowName = UITableViewCell()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        firstTV.delegate = self
        firstTV.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
       
        nameArray.append(nameTF.text!)
        birthdayArray.append(birthdayTF.text!)
        
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       
        rowName.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        return rowName
    }
}
```

Comment: `firstTV.reloadData()` after you append the values to the arrays in `saveButton()` func.

Comment: Thanks, it did work. When i press the button it does save the value but on the second press it deletes previous one. How can i remain more then one data at the same time?

Comment: Hello, @cemogolog. Welcome to stackoverflow.com, whenever you have a problem, you should first search for it to get your answer before submitting a question. Here are. several answers explain how to use table view in detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through a few tutorials on using table views and ***reusable*** table view cells.

I'm going to assume that, in Storyboard, you added a cell to the table view and set its Style to Basic. You need to give that prototype cell an Identifier -- such as "cell":

[image]

Then, in your `cellForRowAt` function, dequeue a reusable instance of that cell.

Here's your modified code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var birthdayTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTV: UITableView!
    
    var nameArray = [String]()
    var birthdayArray = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        firstTV.delegate = self
        firstTV.dataSource = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        nameArray.append(nameTF.text!)
        birthdayArray.append(birthdayTF.text!)
        
        firstTV.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer and kind support.