# Add left/right/up/down spacing in Tableview's cell in different xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have structure like this

```
storyboard → myScene → myView → TableView
```

this is bind in my `ViewController`'s class like this

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

I also have a `cell file` (xib) for my `ShopHistoryCell`. This is added to Viewcontroller's TableView like this

```swift
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShopHistoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShopHistoryCell")
```

and called like this from TableView function

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShopHistoryCell", for: indexPath) as! ShopHistoryCell
cell.delegate = self
...
```

My cell file is just a boilerplate like this

```swift
class ShopHistoryCell: UITableViewCell {
...
```

Problem is that cell is fullscreen wide with no merging, no padding, no spaces between cells.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift/33234181#33234181) approaches but these work for normal cell inside of tableview. Not working in my case

*my `.xib` file is just a `Table View cell` with `Content View` inside

[image: file]

Comment: Did you add any padding in the cell's xib file? If not, why did you expect it to have padding? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I added how the xib file looks like, It only contains the cell. Could you please explain how to add padding to the cell when not parent is present? When I add normal View  inside the cell this is making bad side effect when pressing the cell