# Performs two different task on basis of condition when collectionView Cell selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am facing problem with segue as I want to delete particular cell on particular condition when user select cell.

But I also set segue on cell for detail page of cell item. And whenever I am try to delete it always goes to next screen even delete condition is active.

On LongPress I activate delete condition otherwise it should go normally to next screen.

Comment: check condition first and then     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sequeName" sender:self];

Comment: I am checking condition even it is not working

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender should be uncommented in your VC

Comment: unlink rown level seques , create onefrom source vc to destination directly

Comment: How, I am new in swift

Answer (score 1):

Don't link your button directly to the segue. Control-drag from your source view controller (not your button) to your destination view controller, create a segue of the desired type, and give it a unique identifier.

Then attach an IBAction (not a segue) to your button. In your IBAction method, test your condition(s), and only invoke the segue (using performSegueWithIdentifier) if the conditions are met.

Comment: @Singhak here is demo of what Duncan suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected

Comment: Thanks for link, Let me try this answer