# Presenting a different view when selecting each Cell in a TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to present a different view when selecting each Cell in a Table View.

[image]

I figured out that I have to use this function:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath   indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}
```

What should I add inside the function to make this work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected look that

Comment: You can detect your cell by your `indexPath`, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (not `didDeselect...`), and follow the guide above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        let objOne = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_OneScene") as? OneScene

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objOne!, animated: true)

    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        let objTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_TwoScene") as? TwoScene

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objTwo!, animated: true)

    }
    else
    {
        let objOther = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_OtherScene") as? OtherScene

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objOther!, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and inside the function you could use `indexPath.row` to know witch cell was tapped and then you need to create and push the view you want

```
let viewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIdentifier") as? ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerObj!, animated: true)
```

also, make sure your `navigationController` is not nil

...hope it helps

Comment: indexPath.row represents the index of the cell in the table. Usually the cell should be represented by a ViewModel. Otherwise saying, you need to have an array of viewModels to use, when building cell contents.