# Passing data with segue from UITableView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to pass data from my UITableView to a UIViewController to show more detail.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "PassDetail" {

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ToDoListDetailViewController
            let customIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            vc.titleString = userList[userList.count - customIndexPath!.row - 1].Title
            vc.descriptionString = userList[userList.count - customIndexPath!.row - 1].Description

        }

    }
```

I created a `segue push depricated` and set the appropriate identifier.

After running, nothing is happening. No crash, I tried setting create print methods and nothing is called when I tap on a cell.

I tried to see if there is a value in my strings to pass with print statements and I did not hear back from my print statements.

Even if there isn't any data, the app should at least crash when I tap on a cell. But it doesn't.

I tried using different segues like `show` and stuff but that did not do the trick.

Am I missing something from my code?

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution.

This is how I understand how this works.
The code I have above passes the data, but it does not push to the next viewcontroller.

To solve this problem, I used the didelectRowAtIndexPath method and set my strings.

Below is my full working code.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
    contentTitle = "Some title" //contentTitle is a global variable

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let row = indexPath.row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("PassData", sender: row)

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "PassData" {

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ToDoListDetailViewController
        vc.titleString = contentTitle //setting the titleString created from my ToDoListDetailViewController and setting it to contentTitle

    }

}
```

Comment: The first thing you should try and see is, whether "userList[userList.count - customIndexPath!.row - 1].Title" has any value. Put a print statement after you set the vc variables and see what happens. Also make sure your segue identifier is correct

Comment: @The_Curry_Man I did that and I did not hear back from my print statement. Even if there isn't a value in my userList, it should at least crash but I it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I suspect, you have not programmatically pushed your segue.

Taking hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected), did you push the segue from your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I originally tried to push the segue, but the proper way is to show the segue. But that did not work either.

Comment: That's okay, but did you do it manually from you didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: hmm, no I don't have that actually. I'll get back to you when I get the chance go try that