# TableView cell is not pushing to next view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I created the single view application using storyboard.

In storyboard file, i have three view controller

> 1-navigation controller 2-Recipe Book View Controller 3-View
>   Controller

Prototype cell of the table view of Recipe Book View Controller is connected through push segue to View Controller.Is the problem Recipe Book View Controller does not navigate to View Controller?
here is the sample of project for download.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5pNDpbvZ8SnLTd1R3NBTE1ReEk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Check your project.

Do following steps:-

1. In `Main.storyboard`, click on Push segue to `ViewController` and add name of identifier
2. Go to `ViewController.m` and paste below code

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueName" sender:self];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Following mistakes are found in your project.

1. There is no class for Third VC.
2. PrepareForSegue not implemented.
3. You wanted to push VC on TableViewCell selection but there you does not implemented `didSelect` tableview delegate.

Comment: I am following this tutorial ..   http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/

Comment: @user2557829 Download full source project from appCoda and check the points that I mentioned.

Comment: Take ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

Select the segue connecting RecipeBookViewController to ViewController , Then give that segue an identifier, i.e. "ViewControllerSegue".

Implement the delegate method of table view and call the performSegueWithIdentifier method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerSegue" sender:tableView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Source code you have to add some code & classes in your project to achieve your requirement.

**1st** You have to add `RecipeViewController` to control your Recipe List and Tableview both.

**2nd** as You have created this `RecipeViewController` you need to assign this class to respective `ViewController` in your storyboard.

**3rd** Assign Segue from PrototypeCell to ViewController where you need to push.

Hope you can understand whats wrong in your Code.